# How do I install a package for different Python versions in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have Python 2.7 as root. I need to install the package "statistics" in Python 3.6, and it is not in the environments of anaconda navigator. How can install "statistics" with `conda` or `pip` for a secondary Python environment?

Comment: See the docs on creating a separate environment [here](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#create-a-separate-environment)

Comment: And also here: https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html

Answer (score 13):

Create a new Python 3 environment by running:

```
conda create --name python3 python=3
```

If you want all the standard anaconda packages installed by default, do:

```
conda create --name python3 python=3 anaconda
```

Whenever you need to use `python3` run:

```
activate python3
```

Then use the command line as normal. So, if you want to install something into your `python3` environment, make sure you `activate python3` first.

Note that python 3 [has it's own statistics module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) that you may find useful, and this module [has been ported to python 2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statistics) if you would prefer.

Comment: `conda create --name python3 python=3.6 anaconda` - if you want to install a whole Anaconda in python3 (`numpy`, etc.)

Comment: I have installed the package using a different venv. Now when I try to import that package into my python file I get an error. That module is not defined.

Comment: Hi @MaujMishra - could you ask a new question as `venv`s are not the same as conda environments so behaviour will differ, and we're missing quite a bit of context that we'd need to help you :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have posted my question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758907/python-package-installed-using-different-version-of-python-gives-modulenotfounde.