# How to use a specific build of Python in my virtual environment

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual environment with a specific build of python (specifically, 3.6.7) to develop locally because I am pushing my code to a Heroku stack which only supports this version of Python 3 ( see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version) ).

As I understand it, this specific build of python must already be installed on my machine so I can do something like `virtualenv --python=/path/to/python3.6.7 env_directory`. My questions are:

1. What is the easy way to install Python-3.6.7 on both Ubuntu and OSX (I will be developing in both operating systems)?
2. Is there some virtual environment tool out there that can download a specific build automatically?

Comment: you could try using Anaconda. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707369/how-do-i-install-a-package-for-different-python-versions-in-anaconda

Comment: Did you see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get ?

Answer (score 0):

Pyenv ( https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv ) lets you easily install multiple versions of python on your system.