# How to install deprecated/unsupported Python 3.4 on conda environment?

Tags: installation, conda, python-3.4, deprecated

Since the deprecation of Python 3.4, conda has removed it from its package list. Is there a way, however, that I can install it?

I need it in order to use software written in this older version.

EDIT:
My question is different than the [suggested duplicate one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707369), because I am referring to deprecated and unsupported versions. I already know how to create a conda environment with a specific python version, but executing:

```
conda create --name py34env python=3.4
```

results in error (listed in the end), which is due to the lack of the package for Python 3.4 .
One can see the currently supported versions of Python by executing: `conda search python` and can confirm that Python 3.4 is not on the list.

This is the output of the error when trying to create a Python 3.4 conda enviroment:

```
$ conda create --name py34env python=3.4
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.4

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a package for different Python versions in Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707369/how-do-i-install-a-package-for-different-python-versions-in-anaconda). Even though Anaconda/MiniConda no longer *run on* older Python versions (i.e., they can't be in **base** env), you can still create environments that run any version [in the repository](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files), which includes everything from 3.3.0 on.  In your case, `conda create -n py34 python=3.4` should get you started.

Comment: Hello @merv, I have already tried the command you suggest and it results in an error because it seems that Anaconda has dropped support for Python 3.4 . See my edited question for more details.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra info! Yeah, I see now it's a Conda 4.7+ thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When [Anaconda dropped it's **free** channel](https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/) (technically, Conda 4.7+ just no longer looks there), this resulted in some older package versions that had never been ported to **main** no longer being accessible.

### Option 1: Globally enable `free` channel searching

However, there is an option to restore access to the **free** channel, namely `restore_free_channel`.

```bash
# Not generally recommended
conda config --set restore_free_channel True
conda create -n py34 python=3.4
```

This isn't generally recommended (see [blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/)), but if you will be working in Python v3.4 frequently and will require other older compatible packages, it might be the best option.

### Option 2: Temporarily include `free` channel

A more temporary solution is to include the `free` channel using the *ad hoc* `--channel,-c` argument. For example,

```bash
# slightly better
conda create -n py34 -c defaults -c free python=3.4
```

Note that I include `defaults` prior to `free` so that the latter will only be used if the package cannot be sourced from the former. This assumes the `channel_priority` setting is set to `flexible` (the default).

### Option 3: Use Conda Forge

Alternatively, Conda Forge has Python v3.4.5, and that won't force you to change a global configuration option.

```bash
conda create -n py34 -c conda-forge python=3.4
```

Comment: I believe that the second solution is the best one, since, as you noted, one does not have to change the global settings. Thanks @merv :)