# Creating python 3.3 environment in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I would like to create a python 3.3 environment in Anaconda (latest Minicoda3 installed).

I tried using `conda create -n py33 python=3.3`:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.3

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

(I added conda-forge too in case there is a python 3.3 version there). Looking up the Anaconda and Conda-forge repositories, it seems to me that python 3.3 is deprecated, as it is not listed among the available packages.

However, I would need to use python 3.3. I would prefer to do it through Anaconda, but it is not strictly necessary. Also, given that Python 3.3 is not available in the Anaconda repo, I suppose additional python packages wouldn't be available either?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha

Comment: I think my question is different, since it regards python itself, not a specific python package.

Comment: here is a similar question on the superuser site: https://superuser.com/questions/622461/how-do-i-create-a-python-3-3-environment-with-anaconda-windows

Comment: That question is more than three years old. I already tried every suggested answer there, since that is how creating a new environment should be done in a normal case; however in this case the missing python 3.3 from the anaconda repo complicates the situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install deprecated/unsupported Python 3.4 on conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449169/how-to-install-deprecated-unsupported-python-3-4-on-conda-environment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that Python 3.3 is available in the 'free' repository:

```
conda create -n py33 python=3.3 --channel free
```

This worked flawlessly.