# conda / miniconda distribution for Python 3.4

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

[Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) distribution is only available for Python 3.8 , how could I find something for a windows machine and compatible with python 3.4 ?

Comment: Are you looking for miniconda or the anaconda stack in particular? Are you aware that Python 3.4 is *very* old and [no longer actively supported](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0429/)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi miniconda is preferred. And yes I know that 3.4 is very old, but I am using a script which is written in 3.4 and  I need this version to run the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install deprecated/unsupported Python 3.4 on conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449169/how-to-install-deprecated-unsupported-python-3-4-on-conda-environment)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a conda environment with python 3.4.

That is, you would install normal conda with python 3.8, create an environment with python 3.4:

```
>conda create --name py34 python=3.4 --channel free
>conda activate py34
>python
Python 3.4.5 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 14:53:07) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

More details here:
[How to install deprecated/unsupported Python 3.4 on conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449169/how-to-install-deprecated-unsupported-python-3-4-on-conda-environment) and [Creating python 3.3 environment in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63358023/creating-python-3-3-environment-in-anaconda)