# Python Package installed using different version of python gives ModuleNotFoundError when importing

Tags: python, anaconda, python-venv

I want to install PyTorch version 1.3.0, which can only be installed in python 3.7 or less. I have python 3.9. So I created a different venv that can run according to python 3.7 ([How do I install a package for different Python versions in Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707369/how-do-i-install-a-package-for-different-python-versions-in-anaconda)).
After installing PyTorch 1.3.0 using the command `conda install pytorch==1.3.0`, When I try to access the library in my Python file it gives an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`

Comment: Did you try `conda activate py37` or whatever your environment name is for python 3.7 and then installing?

Comment: Yes, The install was successfull. But I cant access the module even after installing

Comment: Where are you running the Python file from? Are you in the right environment there too?

Comment: I am using PyCharm. What do you mean by the right environment?

Comment: [Configure a Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) in pycharm

Comment: So, should I set my python interpreter to Python3.7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set default PyCharm interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679150/how-to-set-default-pycharm-interpreter)

Comment: No, I know how to change the interpreter. I want to know how to solve the ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: By changing the interpreter :/